# WP7 Get Wi-Fi gateway IP address

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there someway to get the IP address of the gateway the phone is currently connected to?
I tried searching through the msdn library but did not succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no API to obtain that information available.

Comment: At least, there is no official one (you can get it through undocumented calls, but better not use it). Another method is calling some "whatismyip" webservice to retrieve the information.